# SHA-1 Certificate warning on Windows7

Tags: tls, cryptography, certificates, chrome, sha

I have installed a clean Win7 machine on a network where my own PC is connected.
When I navigate to google.com from my PC (Win 8.1) I receive proper valid TLS connection.
Yet when I navigate to google.com from the Win7 machine I get an error which says:
"This page is insecure (broken HTTPS)" and after that a warning about a SHA-1 certificate.

Why is this happening? What is the difference in the certificate of each machine?

Comment: What does iexplore report? What does Firefox report? What does Chrome report?

Comment: Show us the certificate chain and details for the leaf certificate presented to the respective systems.

Comment: I think google chooses its cert based on which client it thinks you're using. Perhaps it uses a SHA1 cert because it thinks that your client doesn't support anything newer.

Comment: @CodesInChaos That presents pretty much the same problem that I am asking about in [How can different paths on the same domain have different TLS encryption?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/103094/10915) (which is as of yet unanswered, hint hint).

Answer (score 0):

What is likely happening is that Google decides that your browser / system doesn't have the right trust point (root CA's) installed. No doubt Windows 7 supports SHA-2 - that is SHA-256 / SHA-512 and possibly more.

However, if you still have CA certs that contain just SHA-1-based signatures or if you have CA certs that only *issued* SHA-1 certificates (to Google) then the verification of the certificate chain depends on SHA-1.

You can easily click on the lock icon to go to the certificates, then to Certification Path and then finally view each certificate and look for SHA-1. You can ignore the "thumbprint algorith" as the thumbprint is calculated locally on your machine; it's not part of the certificate itself.

This should explain the warning.